# Ng command not found angular

Tags: node.js, angular, bash, npm

I'm trying to install angular but I cant get my pc to find the ng command.
I have tried aliassing, changing the path variable, uninstalling the angular package, updating node and npm.

I think it's a path problem but I'm not too familiar with this.

In the node.js terminal:

```
C:\Users\Calvin Swinnen>where ng
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
```

In the VSCode integrated terminal:

```
Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ ng
bash: ng: command not found

Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
+-- @angular/cli@6.0.1
+-- create-react-app@1.5.2
+-- create-react-native-app@1.0.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
`-- npm@6.0.1

npm ERR! missing: opn@~5.3.0, required by @angular/cli@6.0.1
npm ERR! missing: yargs-parser@^10.0.0, required by @angular/cli@6.0.1

[![Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ npm root
C:\Users\Calvin Swinnen\node_modules

Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ npm root -g
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules
```

I have added the global adress to this paths but no succes

[image: Paths in windows]

With the alias there is a problem with the space in the path:
Maybe I could try this first but it would be nice if it just works without aliassing

```
Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ alias ng="C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin"

Calvin Swinnen@DESKTOP-UJODPIS MINGW64 ~/Documents/vakken/web 4/test
$ ng
bash: C:Program: command not found
```

In normal windows terminal

```
C:\Users\Calvin Swinnen>ng
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks in advance,
Calvin

Comment: What if you just use a regular cmd prompt? Does it resolve ng command there?

Comment: I have added it in the post now, thanks. 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: What's the command line you used to install angular-cli I noticed your path is referencing to GIT folder, should be under your AppData\Roaming\npm. The command to install angular cli should be `npm install -g @angular/cli` Here's the link to [github of angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: I used git Bash as the integrated terminal in vs code, ill try to install in appdata/roaming/npm with the regular cmd when I get home.

Comment: visual studio  or visual studio code?

Comment: Visual studio code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want type of custom configuration - may be you'll face error max of the time.

Anyway, put `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\` as your PATH. Then close all instance of `git-bash` and `vscode` and `cmd`. Then try `ng`.

Before doing all, try to find `ng.cmd` in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\` ... I hope it will be there.

Comment: This worked! But what do you mean by custom configuration?
I thank you very much